# Laravel service provider could not be found. why?

Tags: php, symfony, laravel

I have problem for my service provider.

I have made a folder called library. Autoloaded it. Everything fine. Every class that I add here works just fine. Now, I want to make Facades.

My class is `HT()`

Then I made a file with the following content in it:

```
class HTServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('\Aone\HTML_NS\HT', function()
        {
            return new HT; // Name of your class, be sure to include the namespace     if you are using one.
        });
    }
}
```

But when I add that to app.php ServiceProviders array, it throws the following error:

```
 Class 'Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider\HTServiceProvider' not found
```

Here is the line added to app.php:

```
"Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider\HTServiceProvider",
```

Also I added the namespace to the `app() bind`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can we see your `ServiceProviders` array in `app.php`?  Also, try running a `composer dump-autoload` or `php composer.phar dump-autoload`.

Comment: Does your class have `<?php namespace Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider`?

Comment: thanks, I did that that problem solved but I came up with another error:
`Call to undefined method Aone\HTML_NS\HT::isDeferred() `

Comment: Have you solved your problem? if so, please mark the correct answer (or add it, if it's not the one below). It looks like you're having another issue, but I'm not sure. If you are, ask a new question.

Comment: The answer given didn't solve my problem, the comment above did. here is the link to my new question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798534/laravel-serviceprovide-issue-that-says-isdeferred-is-not-found

Answer (score 1):

probably you just need to namespace it:

```
$this->app->bind('Your\Namespace\HT', function()
```

Comment: I did that, dump-autoloaded but still nothing